# SPOJ "abs(a-b) I" Wrong Answer issue

Tags: algorithm, debugging, math

This is my approach for the problem statement http://www.spoj.com/problems/ABSP1/ - please check if there is any corner case on which my code is falling because according to my test cases it is giving correct answer.

**Problem Statement:**

> You are given an array of N numbers in non-decreasing order. You have
>   to answer the summation of the absolute difference of all distinct
>   pairs in the given array.

scanf("%d",&TotalElements);

```
    for(i=0;i<TotalElements;i++)
       scanf("%d",&Array[i]);

    FirstSum=TotalSum=0;        
    for(i=0;i<TotalElements;i++)
       FirstSum+=abs(Array[i]-Array[0]);

    TotalSum=FirstSum;
    SumTillNow=Array[0];
    for(i=1;i<TotalElements;i++){

        Difference=Array[i]-Array[0];
        NextSum=FirstSum-Difference*(TotalElements-i)-SumTillNow+(i)*Array[0];          
        TotalSum+=NextSum;
        SumTillNow+=Array[i];

    }

    printf("%lld\n",TotalSum);
```

Comment: Can you give some brief explanation for your code, as well as the problem statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem setter doesn't seem to have enough experience. Here's why:

1. He says distinct pairs but it doesn't seem like it. Maybe what he meant to say was UNORDERED pairs.
2. The test data doesn't conform to the constraints. Asserts on input data verify this. Use 64 bit signed integers for input.

Make changes to your program keeping these two point in mind (especially point 2) and it should get accepted.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment? For comment, you can add under the question

Comment: @PhamTrung An answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to me your logic is fine. 
**I think the Wrong Answer may be related to the types of variables that you have used.**

Let's look at this statement in your code closely.

```
NextSum=FirstSum-Difference*(TotalElements-i)-SumTillNow+(i)*Array[0];

Here FirstSum = summation( A[k] - A[0] ) for all k > 0
              = summation( A[k] ) - N*A[0]

Difference = A[i] - A[0].
```

Hence the statement becomes:

```
NextSum = summation( A[k] ) - N*A[0] - (A[i] - A[0])*(N-i) - summation( A[j] ){j<i} + i*A[0]
        = summation( A[m] ){m >= i} - A[i]*(N-i)
```

This sum takes into account all the absolute differences between `A[i]` and `A[m]` where `m > i`. This should give you the correct answer.

Also, there is a simpler way to carry out the summation. I include it for completeness.

If you look at the number of times each A[i] will appear in the sum of absolute differences,

"-A[0]" will appear N-1 times
"-A[1]" will appear N-2 times and A[1] will appear 1 time. Hence net effect will be `(1 - (N-2))*A[1]`.

Similarly A[i]th term shall be `(i - (N-i-1))*A[i]` = `(2i + 1 - N)*A[i]`.

You can calculate the series accordingly.

Comment: I got it accepted using the same logic but just changed the int to long long int

Answer (score 0):

One things come to mind. SPOJ says:

```
Do you know what distinct pair means? Suppose you have an array of 3 elements: 3 5 6
Then all the distinct pairs are:
3 5
3 6
5 6
```

If you instead had the array of 3 elements: 3 3 4 then how many distinct pairs do you have? Similarly for: 3 3 3. SPOJ doesn't exactly clarify what a distinct pair is but I assume two pairs a1 a2 and b1 b2 are only distinct if a1 <> a2 or b1 <> b2. If this is the case then you will need to filter out all duplicates in the array.

Comment: It doesn't matter, as the different between non - distinct pair is zero

Comment: @PhamTrung it does. Answer for 1 2 is 1 but for 1 2 2 is 2

Comment: @shebang in which way? your example clearly show that we should not filter out the duplicate.

Comment: @PhamTrung I am sorry if I weren't clear. I tried to point out that it does in fact matter.